# Invoke Java class in jsp page

Tags: java, jsp

I need your help guys I have this JAVA class which allows monitoring data from a central processor unit (CPU), I need to invoke or display the output from the Java class into a JSP OR SERVLET web page.

```
        package cpudata;

        import java.math.BigInteger;
        import java.util.Random;
        import org.hyperic.sigar.CpuInfo;
        import org.hyperic.sigar.CpuPerc;
        import org.hyperic.sigar.ProcCpu;
        import org.hyperic.sigar.Sigar;
        import org.hyperic.sigar.SigarException;

        /**
            *
            * @author alsadig
            */
        public class CpuData {

            private static Sigar sigar;

            public CpuData(Sigar s) throws SigarException {
                sigar = s;
                System.out.println(cpuInfo());
            }

            public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, SigarException {
                new CpuData(new Sigar());
                CpuData.startMetricTest();
            }
            private static void startMetricTest() throws InterruptedException, SigarException {
                new Thread() {
                    public void run() {
                        while(true) 
                        BigInteger.probablePrime(MAX_PRIORITY, new Random());
                    };
                }.start();
                while(true) {
                    String pid = ""+sigar.getPid();
                    System.out.print(getMetric(pid));
                    for(Double d:getMetric()){
                        System.out.print("\t"+d);
                    }
                    System.out.println();
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }       
            }

            public String cpuInfo() throws SigarException {
                CpuInfo[] infos = sigar.getCpuInfoList();
                CpuInfo info = infos[0];

                String infoString = info.toString();
                if ((info.getTotalCores() != info.getTotalSockets())
                        || (info.getCoresPerSocket() > info.getTotalCores())) {
                    infoString+=" Physical CPUs: " + info.getTotalSockets();
                    infoString+=" Cores per CPU: " + info.getCoresPerSocket();
                }

                long cacheSize = info.getCacheSize();
                if (cacheSize != Sigar.FIELD_NOTIMPL) {
                    infoString+="Cache size...." + cacheSize;
                }
                return infoString;
            }

            public static Double[] getMetric() throws SigarException {
                CpuPerc cpu = sigar.getCpuPerc();
                double system = cpu.getSys();
                double user = cpu.getUser();
                double idle = cpu.getIdle();
                return new Double[] {system, user, idle};
            }

            public static double getMetric(String pid) throws SigarException {
                ProcCpu cpu = sigar.getProcCpu(pid);
                return cpu.getPercent();
            }

        }
```

Comment: You can create object and call appropriate method of this class.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to call Java code from JSP:

**First:** Calling method from Scriptlet, (not the good approach):

```
<%= com.example.MyUtility.getSomething() %>
```

**Second:** Setting the object in request and fetching the object on JSP, like below:

In Servlet:

```
request.setAttribute("yourData", MyUtility.methodToCall())
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("yourJSP.jsp");
dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

In yourJSP.jsp:

```
${yourData}
```

**Third:** Importing the class on JSP using page directive and instantiating it and calling the method, as below:

```
<%@page import="com.example.MyUtility"%>
<%
   MyUtility obj = new MyUtility ();
   obj.methodToCall();
%>
```